spring rest docs snippet not created
i was trying to apply spring rest docs in my project, and so i was following the guide from the official reference site. but i couldn't make any snippets.
this is my build.gradle.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert' version '3.3.2'
}

group = 'study'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    asciidoctorExt
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.3'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.3'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3'

    asciidoctorExt 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('asciidoctor') {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    configurations 'asciidoctorExt'
    dependsOn test
}

tasks.register('copyDocument', Copy) {
    dependsOn asciidoctor

    from file("build/docs/asciidoc/")
    into file("src/main/resources/static/docs")
}

build {
    dependsOn copyDocument
}

and this is my test.
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SsenseApplicationTests.class);
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RegisterExtension
    final RestDocumentationExtension restDocumentation = new RestDocumentationExtension("custom");

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup((webApplicationContext))
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void join() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/join")
                        .param("username", "test")
                        .param("password", "1234"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("join", formParameters(
                        parameterWithName("username").description("username"),
                        parameterWithName("password").description("password")
                        )
                ));
    }

    @Test
    void login() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("test").password("1234"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("login",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));
    }

the test just works fine. i tried everything and this was the best i could got but it still doesn't create any snippets. help me

I can't see anything that's obviously wrong. Where have you looked for the snippets? You could try debugging the handle method of org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler to see what it does.
